# How do I save intermediate fractional results when the input and output should be integer?

Tags: c#, types, casting

I'm trying to create a BMI calculator using c#.

```
My formula is BMI = (weight /(height * height)) * factor.
Example:      BMI = (172 / (73 * 73 )) * 703
              BMI = (172 / 5329) * 703
              BMI = ( 0.032) * 703
              BMI =   22.69
```

My problem is that after I divide the weight by the height I'm getting a fraction, despite the fact that when I multiply it by the factor it's above 1, I can't save it in my integer variable. So my total BMI is always coming out at 0.

Do I need to rethink my data types? or should I be converting them? I'm unsure how to resolve the issue.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Calculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int feet, inches, height, pounds, result, factor;
        factor = 703;

        //convert the text input to the correct data type
        feet = Convert.ToInt32(feetBox.Text);
        inches = Convert.ToInt32(inchesBox.Text);
        pounds = Convert.ToInt32(poundsBox.Text);

        //turn the feet and inches into a single height value in inches
        height = (feet * 12) + inches;

        //calculate the BMI
        //result = (pounds / (height * height) ) * factor;
        result = factor * (pounds / (height * height));

        // output the results
        output.Text = String.Format("Your BMI is: {0}", result);
    }
}
```

Comment: The value is 172, its pounds in the code block

Comment: change your result datatype to double

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are facing integer division. If you divide integer by integer the result is again integer. To fix this problem you have to cast value to floating type (float/double). That will fix the problem.

`double result = factor * (pounds / (double)(height * height));`

This way you will force the result to be decimal number.

EDIT:
The problem is following. Imagine the integers as physical objects - apples for example.

`7/3` you have `7` apples, and you want to give to `3` kids. How many apples will each kid get? The answer is `2`. The remainder is 1 of course. But the integer division doesn't return the remainder, so this information is 'lost' in the process of division.

When programming, the rule of thumb is, to stick with integer as long as it is possible. Because of the way decimal number are stored in memory, there are some errors. Note that up to some arbitrary value integers can be stored in floating types without loss of precision, but starting at the threshold, there are errors even for integer numbers.
Try `123456789` in the float converter below, it won't be stored exactly, that's why is better to stick with integers as long, as you can.

Great tool to examine those imperfections is this [float converter](http://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/). For example `0.5` can be stored precisely but `0.6` cannot. Try it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You should never get a negative number from a division of 2 positive numbers. Therefore if you are getting a negative result one of your inputs is a negative number (and as you are multiplying height by itself the negative must be coming from the weight).

If you want the result to be an `integer` value then moving the `factor` multiplier inside the parenthesis would be ok:

```
int result = (factor * weight) / (height * height);
```

This would work because `factor * weight` will always be larger than `height * height`, and hence the answer will a none-zero integer.

If you want decimals in your result (which BMI usually contains e.g. `22.6`) then you need to perform floating point division, rather than integer division. The easiest way to do this would be to change all of your variables to `double`, rather than `int`, or to simple introduce a decimal number into to the equation at the beginning. The following would produce the correct result:

```
double factor = 703.0;
double result = (factor * weight) / (height * height);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to change the data type of BMI (result) from int to double. I hope then everything will work.

Please replace existing line of code : `int feet, inches, height, pounds, result, factor;`

with

double feet, inches, factor, result, height, pounds,  ;

Comment: Still not working? The final value of 22.69 too big for a double type?

Comment: 22.69 too big for double? Err, no its not. Nothing to do with BMI should have any issues with double, single, even short would be fine, as people just don't weight millions of pounds nor are millions of inches tall.

Comment: It seems that something else is wrong. 22.69 value is not big for double data type. Can you post the error message, you are getting. It will help us to understand the problem

Comment: Ok. So i'm storing the results of 172 / 5329 into a double and i'm still getting 0 as the output.

Comment: I'm not getting an error. The value of my results variable is returning 0

Comment: Have you changed the data types of variables as I mentioned in my solution?

Comment: Change the type of all variables to double in order to keep things simple. Otherwise, you have to cast the result of "(feet * 12) + inches" into double.